# android studio google gms play services version conflict

Tags: android, dependencies, google-play-services

i have a problem with my gms google services for android studio ,
when i reload a gradle sync it would be error

here's my message error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

NB:my classpath :play-services version 3.0.0

Comment: show your gradle

Comment: gradle ? did you mean android monitor?

Comment: 23/06/2017


10.38 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

10.38 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 9s 455ms

10.39 Gradle sync started

10.40 Gradle sync completed

10.40 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

10.40 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 6s 846ms

Comment: gradle is where you put your dependencies..

Comment: follow the suggested solution by your IDE which is 'Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.'

Comment: thanks bruh , problem solved